# C++ Increment multidimensional array size

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function that saves data on a 2D array. The problem is, the array is to be sent on the internet 50 times a second, so I want the size of the array to be as little as possible, with no waste. So, let's say that my program manages to update 3 times in this 50th of a second, i want the second dimension of the array to be exatly 3. If it updates 10 times, it'll be 10, if just 1, it'll be 1. I am trying to achieve this by incresing the second dimension size by 1 before every update.

```
char* a[254];

/* every tick */ 

for (int i=0; i<254; i++)
{
    a[i]=new char[counter]; //counter is incremented by one every update
}
```

would this work, or it would just move the bounds of the array and mess the already existing data up?

EDIT: I'll try to explain a little bit better. If I have a [2][2] array, the third position is [2][1]. Let's say all the array is 0 except for [2][1] wich is 1. Now, if i increment the second dimension with `new`, will 1 be moved to the new [2][1] position or it would still remain on the third, wich is now [1][3]?

Comment: Well this allocates new space , it doesn't move anything.

Comment: Why don't you just send the data you want to send, regardless of how much memory was allocated?

Comment: "The array is to be sent on the internet..." You have an array of memory locations that are unique to your machine. I don't know what good they'll do anyone on the interwebs...

Comment: There's nothing that says you have to send all the data in the array. Just maintain a counter of the number of updates and calculate the number of bytes to send from that and other information about the array. Something like `bytes = updates * arrayWidth;`. Regardless of what solution you find I suggest using `std::vector` instead of managing memory yourself.

Comment: @Josh nope, I can already send the 2D array I was just asking how to reduce the badwidth, but the "sending" problem is already overcomed.

Comment: What you are doing is initializing a 2D array. This is how you initialize it and it has nothing to do with update or reducing array size. If you are doing an update like this, then you should realize that every time you call "NEW" you are actually allocating memory so you are not changing the previous element at that particular memory allocation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, every "new" call will allocate new memory w/o copying the already existing data. Moreover memory leak will met

Comment: He could very well be properly managing `a` after this code block. It's a little unfair to assume there will be a memory leak when the only code you see is him allocating memory...